# How to proof whether these vectors are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, roots-of-unity

Let $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$ be two distinct roots of unity.

Let $v \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ be the vector given by

$$v_i = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1-i} \lambda^j,  \ i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$$

that is
$$v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + \lambda + \lambda^2 +  \cdot\cdot\cdot + \lambda^{n-3}+ \lambda^{n-2} \\
1 + \lambda + \lambda^2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot  +  \lambda^{n-3} \\
\cdot\cdot\cdot
\\
1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Another way to write this would be that $v$ is given by the product
$$ M \tilde{v}$$
where $M$ is the matrix
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1& \cdot \cdot \cdot & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1& \cdot \cdot \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
& & & \cdot \cdot \cdot & & \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot \cdot \cdot & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $\tilde{v}_i = \lambda^i$.

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ be the vector given by $$w_i = \overline{\mu^i}.$$
That is,
$$\overline{w} = (\mu,\mu^2,\mu^3,...,\mu^{n-1}).$$

The inner product of $v,w$ is then given by

$$\langle v, w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1-i} \lambda^j \mu^i.$$

I want to check whether it always holds that $\langle v,w \rangle \neq 0$.

Is there a neat way to proof/disprove this?

**Edit:**
According to the comment, geometric sums might be of help.

Indeed we have (for $\lambda \neq 1$)

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1-i} \lambda^j = \frac{1-\lambda^{n-i}}{1-\lambda}$$

Thus we get
$$\langle v, w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1-\lambda^{n-i}}{1-\lambda} \mu^i = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu^i - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\mu\lambda^{-1})^i}{1-\lambda}=\frac{-1 -(-1)}{1-\lambda} = 0$$

Comment: the two definitions of $v$ are not the same

Comment: Also, are they $n$-th roots of unity? and $w$ in the last part of the question is $\mu$?
Anyway, geometric sequences should be enough for this one

Comment: @Exodd: you are correct, I fixed the definitons. Yes they are $n-$th roots of unity, but I included only $n-1$ terms since the remaining one will anyway sum to zero (if $\lambda \neq 0$). Anyway, geometric sequences seem to have been the right tip, care to check if I didn't make a mistake?

Comment: You still have to prove it in the case $\lambda=1$